# I get 500 Internal Server Error after 30 seconds of running a script

Tags: php, plesk

The production server has CentOS 6.4 with Plesk 11.0.9. It is a dedicated server.

**Server configuration:**
* `max_execution_time` is set to 500 from Plesk and it shows up correctly in `phpinfo`

**Problems:**
* I get `500 Internal Server Error` after 30 seconds of running any script

Is there any way I get a workaround this problem?

**LE:**
* the script I want to do this downloads from a remote location a file to user's browser. It might require even hours to complete the operation (for very slow internet connection clients). I really need this. And one more thing, the user must not see the source url.

Comment: Check your error logs to see exactly why it's failing

Comment: If you're querying database, it could aswell be the database request timeout. And as a side note, I know this is very tempting and all 'especially when uploading files for example), but if you've got a web script running for more than 30 seconds, then it should probably be whether optimized whether replaced by a non-web script... Or at leat the timeout extension should be altered only with this script, not for your whole site.

Comment: @Bartdude: I have edited the question to let you know what the script does

Comment: Depending on how you're downloading the file, you could be hitting your memory limit.

Comment: Well, as I said, you're probably not doing it as it should. You definitely should delegate the download task to a non-web script, and warn the user (through mail or whatever) when the file is ready for him to download. Especially if it can take hours...

Comment: @Bartdude:If the user downloads the file through my script, it will take x seconds to download. But if I download the file first and then inform the user, it will take x seconds from the first request plus y seconds to actually download it. It is unacceptable.

Comment: Then supposing you can do it (meaning this remote location is accessible from server-side to a protocol allowing remote opening), you would need to open the file server side in order to read it and send it back to the user, which will cause memory problems as suggested by dleiftah in previous comment, in opposition to the timeouts problems you've got. Extending therequest timeout time to several hours is anyway a very very bad idea.

Comment: @dleiftah and @Bartdude: the script basically `fopen`s the url, read chunks of 8192 bytes and echo that out. That a look [here](http://pastebin.com/16m0DWJg)

Comment: @dleiftah: how can I check how much memory it uses at certain point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you run Fast CGI. The CGI process has a maximum execution time. In fastcgi its the **idle-timeout**. After that you get an 500 Error because the backend is not responding in that time.

I don't know which module you use. But normally you can set the **idle-timeout** in your configuration.

[mod_fastcgi idle timeout not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345016/mod-fastcgi-idle-timeout-not-work)

Comment: The server was running with `Fast CGI`. I switched it to `Apache` and now it seems to work. A simple script like `sleep(70); phpinfo();` now returns the output. Thanks!